# Margin collapse between IMG and H2 element not working

Tags: html, css

Is there a reason why the vertical margin between an image and h2 isn't collapsing?  I have the following code and style.  From all the reading, there is no exception due to it being an img tag.  Is it because an IMG is technically in-line?  In Chrome at least, it has a top and bottom margin added.  Is it better practice to wrap the image in a block element?

```
<section id="test">
    <img src="img/web_dev2@2x.png"/>
    <h2>Test</h2>
</section>
```

Style:

```
img, h2 {
    margin: 2em 0;
}
```

-- EDIT:
When I wrap the img with a P tag and apply margin to it instead, the margin collapses, as expected.  What is best practice then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margin only [collapses](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) between blocks:

> Two margins are [adjoining](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#x28) if and only if:
>
> - both belong to in-flow [block-level boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) that participate in the same [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)
> - [...]

But images are inline-level by default. Blockify it:

```css
img, h2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="test">
  <img src="/favicon.ico"/>
  <h2>Test</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: I guess reading the spec is always a good idea in cases like these